# Using native cpp testframework in visual studio to test c code LNK2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing

I try to set up a test project in Visual Studio 2019.

The module that I want to test is written in c.

I'm using the native VS cpp Testframework.

I can compile and run my program but not my unittest. Once I try to run that one I get the following error:

*Fehler LNK2019 Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol "_is_prime" in Funktion ""public: void __thiscall UnitTest1::UnitTest1::TestMethod1(void)" (?TestMethod1@UnitTest1@1@QAEXXZ)".    UnitTest1   C:\Users\Alexander Leibenath\Documents\20210210_Prime_VS\Primzahlprüfer\Primzahlprüfer\UnitTest1\UnitTest1.obj  1*

What I've tried so far:

- told the comiler in the header file that if he is a cpp compiler he should interpret the c-functions as c

Here is my code:

```
 /* File calc.c ----------------------------------------------- */
 /* Tell if the argument is a prime (ret 1) or not (ret 0) */
 int is_prime(unsigned val)
 {
 unsigned divisor;

 if (val == 1 || val == 2 || val == 3)
     return 1;
 if (val % 2 == 0)
     return 0;
 for (divisor = 3; divisor < val / 2; divisor += 2)
 {
     if (val % divisor == 0)
         return 0;
 }
 return 1;
 }
```

my calc.h

```
  /* File calc.h ----------------------------------------------- */

  /* Tell if the argument is a prime (ret 0) or not (ret 1) */
  #ifdef __cplusplus
  extern "C" {
  #endif
  //C code goes here
  int is_prime(unsigned val);

   #ifdef __cplusplus
   } // extern "C"
   #endif
```

and my unittest cpp file:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include "../Primzahlprüfer/calc.h"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace UnitTest1
{
TEST_CLASS(UnitTest1)
{
public:
    
    TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
    {
        int result;
        result = is_prime(5);
    }
 };
 }
```

I'm thankful for all the help I can get. Thanks

Comment: Apparently unittest.obj isn't linked with the testrunner. Is the main project a DLL or plain executable?

Comment: I think a plain executable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I tested the code, I found that it has nothing to do with the C file.

First of all, you need to check if you have added `..\calc\Debug\*.obj` in `Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies`.

Then, you could add the reference to the `calc` in `References`.
[image]

Comment: Thank you! With that setting I was abled to run the tests.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.